# Graphql Django best way to get nested object property

Tags: python, django, graphql, relay, graphene-python

Instead of doing the query like this

```
query {
    allObjectC {
        id # self ID()
        nestedB_set {
            id
            nestedA_set {
                id # ID() we want to get
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New Graphql Query

```
query {
    allObjectC {
        id # self ID()
        nestedA_id # nested nested ID() we want to get
    }
}
```

Any best pratice or ideas for this ?
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

We change the model like this // Models.py

```
class ObjectA(models.Model):
    ...

class ObjectB(models.Model):
    propertyB = models.ForeignKey(ObjectA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='nestedB')

class ObjectC(models.Model):
    propertyC = models.ForeignKey(ObjectB, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='nestedC')

    @property # new property created
    def nestedB_nestedA_id(self):
        return self.propertyC.nested_objectB.nested_objectA.id
```

We change the graphql schema like this // schema.py

```
class ObjectCNode(DjangoObjectType):

    nestedB_nestedA_id = graphene.Int(source='nestedB_nestedA_id') # as proxy 

    nestedA_id = graphene.ID() # globalID of ObjectANode we want to get

    def resolve_nestedB_nestedA_id(self, info, **kwargs):
        return self.nestedB_nestedA_id

    def resolve_nestedA_id(self, info, **kwargs):
        return relay.Node.to_global_id(ObjectANode._meta.name, self.nestedB_nestedA_id)
```

And now query

```
query {
    allObjectC {
        id # self ID()
        nestedA_id # nested nested ID() we want to get
    }
}
```

Others suggestions ?